# Url forwarding does not work when the target has a base url (NodeJs http-express-proxy)

Tags: node.js, express

I am calling a backend API service with this line in my NodeJs application (Angular):

```
this.http.get<Car[]>('/server/api/v1/cars')
```

But get the following error : GET http://127.0.0.1:4200/server/api/v1/cars 404 (Not Found)

I did expect the url to be translated to http://127.0.0.1:8080/api-baseurl/api/v1/cars with the following server.js (run with`node server.js`) :

```
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
.
.
app.use('/server', proxy('http://localhost:8080/api-baseurl'));
```

But it looks like proxy does not handle forwarding when the target has a base url : using this line `app.use('/server', proxy('http://localhost:8080/api-baseurl'));` worked when the api did not have a base url, but that is non the case anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer. What I did not understand form https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy is that the first proxy() parameter matches the host, not the specific resource path. ProxyReqPathResolver must be used for the resource path, a function in which I can edit the path :

```
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
.
.
// Set our api routes proxy to point to backend server
app.use('/server', proxy('http://localhost:8080', { 
    proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
                updatedPathComplete = '/api-baseurl' + req.url;
                console.log('proxy on /server: ' + req.url + ' => ' + updatedPathComplete);
                return updatedPathComplete;
    }
}));
```

In the console log :

```
> node server-prod.js
API running on 4200
proxy on /server: /api/v1/cars => /api-baseurl/api/v1/cars
```